# database design for gps time series data with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database-design, gps, mongodb-query, bigdata

In my project gps send data to server every 20 second and mostly want to use in two use cases:

1. gps path between two times
2. get last gps location and show it live

I end up with schema at "[MongoDB for Time Series Data](https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data)" tutorial.

I want to save data for every hour/day at single document but I don't know that it is fast for use case number 2, for example what if I have to get data from document that exist at 1000 position of it? is mongodb fast to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb must browse the 1000 results before the 1000 position. Instead it's better to sort with index {date:-1} (or internal ObjectId {_id:-1}) and take the first for the last GPS entry.